# AJAX success function with Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm doing a simple to do list in a project with Laravel. Just to explain, when someone add a `task` it only sends to the database the `id` and the `title` of that task. But in the website it shows the the title of the task, a progress bar and a simple checklist where you can add some "sub tasks".

In regular PHP its working fine, but I really liked to convert that to AJAX in order to stop the continuous refresh in the website when someone add a new task.

The code below shows exactly the block that is created when someone add a new a task (`list.blade.php`)

```
<div class="card-body container">
    @if(count($tasks))
    @foreach ($tasks as $task)
    <!-- Task -->
    <div
        <!-- Task Title -->
        <div>
            <h3 id="task-title" class="text-dark small font-weight-bold">{{$task->title}}
                <span class="text-dark float-right">0</span>
            </h3>

            <div class="progress mb-4">
                <div class="progress-bar role="progressbar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Sub Tasks -->
    <div class="container task">
        @if (count($task->subtasks))
        @foreach ($task->subtasks as $subtask)
        <div class="align-items-center mb-2 task-item">
            <form class="subtask-form-delete" action="{{route('subtasks.destroy', $subtask)}}" method="post">
                <div class="task-checkbox"></div>
                <div class="checkbox-active"><i class="fas fa-check check-item align-middle"></i></div>
                <h4 class="small font-weight-bold task-item-title">{{$subtask->title}}</h4>
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm subtask-delete-option" type="submit">
                    <span class="text subtask-single-button">
                        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </form>
            <form class="subtask-update-form" method="POST" action="{{route('subtasks.update', $subtask)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <input type="hidden" name="tasks_id" value="{{$task->id}}">
            </form>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        @else
        <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center mb-2 task-item-mute">
            <div class="task-checkbox-mute"></div>
            <h4 class="small font-weight-bold task-item-title-mute">Adicione um item</h4>
        </div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <!-- Action Buttons Tasks -->
    <div class="text-right container subTask-buttons">
        <div class="subtask-buttons">
            <form class="subtask-create-form" method="POST" action="{{route('subtasks.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="tasks_id" value="{{$task->id}}">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm add-subtask-buttons">
                <span class="text">Adicionar Item</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown dropdown-task-options no-arrow">
                <button class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="text subtask-single-button"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <h6 class="dropdown-header text-center">Opções da tarefa:</h6>
                    <button class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editTaskModal{{$task->id}}">Editar</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteTaskModal{{$task->id}}">Eliminar Tarefa</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @include('backoffice.tasks.partials.delete')
    @include('backoffice.tasks.edit')
    <br>
    <br>
</div>
@endforeach

@else
<h6 style="text-align: center">Sem Tarefas Registadas</h6>
@endif
```

The code below shows the modal that have the form to add a new task (`add.blade.php`)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addTaskModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addTaskModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header align-items-center">
            <h6 class="modal-title text-dark font-weight-bold">Adicionar Tarefa</h6>
            <button type="button" name="button" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm close-modal-button" data-dismiss="modal">
                <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <span class="line"></span>
        <form method="POST" id="form_add" action="{{route('tasks.store')}}" class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="modal-body">
                @csrf
                <h4 class="small font-weight-bold text-dark task-title">Título da Tarefa</h4>
                <input class="task-title-input" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Adicione um título" maxlength="150">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button href="#" id="button_add" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-success shadow-sm" type="submit">
                    <span class="text">Adicionar</span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-sm btn-secondary shadow-sm" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span class="text">Fechar</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below you can find the AJAX code that I have done so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('#button_add').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "{{route('tasks.store')}}",
            data: {
                title: $("#form_add input[name=title]").val(),
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#addTaskModal").modal('hide');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Finally, my question is, how can I include the block of PHP that contains the `@foreach` to show all tasks in the `success function()` of AJAX in order to print automatically in my page?

Thanks in advance, and I'm really sorry if something isn't good, but I'm relative new to Laravel and AJAX. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do PHP stuff in success function().

`success function()` is in JavaScript and @foreach is in blade template and it is used to make a loop with data from back end by using PHP and HTML.

To do something from the data by Ajax call, you could do it by using JavaScript.

Make HTML with JavaScript and Add it into the element you want instead of using @foreach.

e.g:

```
var element = document.createElement('p');
element.innerHTML = "Text1";
document.querySelector('.class').appendChild(element);
```

Comment: So basically I need to create everything from scratch with JavaScript? There is no such thing as an include() function?

Comment: Yes, there is include() function and it's in blade template and you could not do it with blade template in case you use Ajax. No need for everything). You could just do that for the data from Ajax API call.
To show the result only from back end.

Comment: In that case, i will to it like you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by dynamically add DOM in your ajax call just create a div with id='#task'

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{{route('your route for show data')}}",
    data: "data",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
        var html = "";
        data.forEach(textdata => {
            html+=` <tr id="${textdata.id}">
               <td>${textdata.name}</td>
               <td class="d-flex">
                <button id ="edit-exam"  data-id="${textdata.id}" style="color:white" class="mb-2 mr-2 btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                <button id="delete-exam" data-id="${textdata.id}" class="mb-2 mr-2 btn btn-danger">Delete</button>

               </td>
           </tr>`
           $('#task').html(html);
        });
    }
});
```

it is just a demo design . you can add any html and css design

Comment: Thank you! That's actually something that I was looking for.

Comment: Just one question. What is `textdata`? I mean, what I need to place in that?

Comment: textdata is just a variable you can name it anything ..basically what the code doing is loop through each data and assign it to textdata .
you can name it in your way ... but remember to maintain the same variable name when you display the object value [ for example you can name it tasks and you have to display its value like          <tr id = "${task->id}">

hope you understand

Comment: It actually says that data.forEach is not a function.

Comment: data.quotesArray.forEach(task=>{}) 

use this it should solve it ..